# Why does python allow slices to exceed a list's length?

Tags: python, list

When I was writing code, I noticed a feature was not working as it should. I figured out that the problem came from this strange behavior:

```py
>>> [][:10]
[]
```

I was expecting this code to throw an error. Why doesn't it? What practical applications does this behavior have?

Comment: The relevant part of the  [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html) is "However, out of range slice indexes are handled gracefully when used for slicing:"

Comment: @ch2019 Yes, but why is it handled gracefully? Is there a way to turn this feature "off"?

Comment: "Is there a way to turn it off" - that's a different question.